# How do I approach this problem in N^2 time complexity

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, hashmap

Given an array `A[]` of N integers, the task is to count the number of tuples (i, j, k, l) such that i, j, k and I are distinct integers (1 <= i < j < k <= N) and at least one of the following conditions is

1. `A[i] = A[j] + A[k] + A[l]`
2. `A[j] = A[i] + A[k] + A[l]`
3. `A[k] = A[i] + A[j] + A[l]`
4. `A[l] = A[i] + A[j] + A[k]`

More formally, you have to find the number of groups of four distinct elements in the array `A[]` in which at least one of the element is equal to the sum of other three elements.

```
A.sort()
C = 0
D = dict()
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i + 1, N):
        D[A[i] + A[j]] = (i, j)
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i + 1, N):
        S = A[i] + A[j]
        if S in D and  D[S] != (i, j):
           C += 1
print(C)
```

I'm getting 8 but the answer is 4

Input:

```
N = 5
A = 1 1 3 1 1
```

Output:

```
4
```

Explanation:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 5
1 3 4 5
2 3 4 5
```

Input:

```
N = 2
A = 5 2
```

Output:

```
0
```

Comment: Your code is never checking the sum rules you have given at the top of your question. It checks for forms of `A[i] + A[j] = A[k] + A[l]`. That's not the same rule.

Comment: Do you need worst time complexity of N^2, or on average? The line `D[A[i] + A[j]] = (i, j)` has no worst case complexity of 1.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that you are constantly changing the value in the dictionary, so the D[s] != (i, j) condition results to be true when you don’t want it to.

For example, take your first example list, and take the following portion of your code:

```
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i + 1, N):
        S = A[i] + A[j]
        if S in D and  D[S] != (i, j):
           C += 1
```

You begin with i being the 0 and j being 1. Given that A[0] = 1 and A[1] = 1, S will evaluate to two. When you check if S is in D, that will evaluate to true. However, when you check to see if D[S] != (i, j), that will evaluate to true as well. Why?

Well, in this part of your code:

```
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i + 1, N):
        D[A[i] + A[j]] = (i, j)
```

You originally set D[2] to (0, 1), but later on you set it to (0, 3), then (0, 4), then (1, 3), then (1, 4), and finally (3, 4).

I would recommend using a hash table where your keys are the sums (as you have right now) and the values are lists. Here would be the start of that:

```
D = {}

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i + 1, N):
        S = A[i] + A[j]
        if S not in D:
            D[S] = []
        D[S].append((i, j))
```

and I’ll let you figure out how to write the second part. Note that it is very similar to what you did.